# How to add Docusign API to my swift project

Tags: swift, docusignapi

I need to implement a user to make sign in my app. so after clicking on Draw Sign i need to show interface to sign the user.

"DocuSignAPI" IS this the correct choice for my need ?

How to do with DocuSignAPI?

Who should have Docu sign account ?

Answer (score 0):

As a developer you need an account, client does not need an account to sign - but they can create one if they wish.
Look at this recipe;
https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/signing-from-your-app

in order you need to 
0) Create a template document for clients to sign
1) make a connection to Docusign API
2) create an "envelope" using the template identification you created at Step 0 for the specified client, you may need name and ID for the client.
3) Get the envelope ID from Step 2 and the above recipe will return a URL for that specific clients documents to sign.